# failed when use "git remote add short_name url"

Tags: git

I'm new to git and would like to build a git database for my team. I tried these steps:

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
git remote add short_name /prj/my_prj/item1.git
```

to my understanding, the `/prj/my_prj/item1.git` should be an open repository to all memebers of my team. I then tried to add the database as:

```
cp from_some_database/my_files .
git add my_files
git commit -m "initial checkin"
git push short_name
```

here i got error as:

```
fatal: `/prj/my_prj/item1.git` does not appear to be a git repository
```

can anybody give me some help? thanks.

Comment: Are you plan to use GitHub? If so, start from create repo there and you will see instructions to move forward

Comment: Looks like it's a repository set up on your local FS. Are you sure the path to the repo is correct?

Comment: @ItayB Thanks for your reply. I just use git on my servers.

Comment: @Edmundo yes, the path is correct. I use "pwd" and copied it.

Comment: Not defined on the post but I guess /prj/my_prj/item1.git is a _bare repo_, right? And so ```ls /prj/my_prj/item1.git/config``` does show us config file for said repo, right?

Comment: @Edmundo  hi, I even can not find the file item1.git, it seems not generated in the directory

Comment: Following naming conventions, /prj/my_prj/item1.git _should_ be a bare repo (it's not necessarily so, just a convention) and so I'd expect it to be a directory, not a file.

Comment: @Edmundo Yes, you are right. I didn't noticed this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all of your kind replies. With your help finally I found failure reason and solution.
At start time I think item1.git is a file built by git when using "git init". With Edmoudo and Dave's help I realized that this item1.git is a directory and should be built by

```
     git init --bare --shared item1.git
```

The second thing I realized is that I should clone the database first, i.e.

```
     mkdir work1
     cd work1
     git clone xxxx/item1.git
```

Then in work1/item1 directory can i use command

```
     git remote add short_name xxxx/item1.git
```

at this time i can use short_name for pull/push

Answer (score 0):

Add a shared bare repository to the remote directory first:

```
cd /prj/my_prj
git init --bare --shared item1.git
```

Then return to your local working directory and your push should work:

```
git push short_name master
```